# ROS remote master: can see topics but no data

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, scan, ros-hostname, ros-master-uri

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys

I have already read through several threads like this but couldn't figure out what my issue is..

I have a robot and a remote PC. I want to visualize the lidar data of the robot in rviz on my remote PC.
Now my problem is that I can see with 'rostopic list' the topic /scan but when I try 'rostopic echo /scan' on my remote PC nothing is published. When I try 'rostopic echo /scan' on the robot I can see the data - so it definetly should work!

When I tried roswtf it tells me:
ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:

- /hlds_laser_publisher

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:

- /hlds_laser_publisher->/rviz_1602065662574712563 (/scan)
- /hlds_laser_publisher->/rosout (/rosout)

ERROR Errors connecting to the following services:

- service [/hlds_laser_publisher/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/hlds_laser_publisher/get_loggers], address [rosrpc://robot:53743]
- service [/hlds_laser_publisher/set_logger_level] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with service [/hlds_laser_publisher/set_logger_level], address [rosrpc://robot:53743]

Both are connected to the same network and can ping each other.
Master is my remote PC -> bashrc network configuration is like the following:

remotePC:
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://remotePC:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=remotePC

robot:
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://remotePC:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=robot

I have added the IPs of robot and remotePCo /etc/hosts

I hope somebody can help me with this network configuration issue..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362999/ros-remote-master:-can-see-topics-but-no-data/) by [lslabon](https://answers.ros.org/users/59110/lslabon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-10-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-10-07**:
checking here (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines, at the end) Seems like could be that you forgot to define ROS_IP

**Comment by [lslabon](https://answers.ros.org/users/59110/lslabon/) on 2020-10-08**:
You can define ROS_IP either with export ROS_IP or with export ROS_HOSTNAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assume robot IP is = 192.168.1.10 and remote PC IP is 192.168.1.20
On the robot (the ROS master) run the following commands and then run roscore and any ros node

```
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash  
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.10:11311  
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.10
```

On the remote PC, apply the following settings before running your application:

```
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash  
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.10:11311  
export ROS_IP=192.168.1.20
```

Then try to access robot topics on your remote PC.

**Also**
check your firewalls on both. You can disable your firewall for a quick test:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

---

Originally posted by [afar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32894/afar/) with karma: 111 on 2020-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lslabon](https://answers.ros.org/users/59110/lslabon/) on 2020-10-08**:
Omg ! Can't believe it lol

It was the **firewall**. Thank you guys for your help !